# Read data from Spring batch tables using JPA and EclipseLink

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, spring-batch

I want to read data using JPA and EclipseLink ORM from Spring batch tables which seem not to follow Eclipselink conventions

I am getting exceptions as follows:

```
Runtime Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Column name BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION.CREATE_TIME does not follow DateTime type convention. Use suffix [_TS] due to conventions.

java.lang.NullPointerException

    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:715) ~[org.eclipse.persistence.core-2.6.2.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:651) ~[org.eclipse.persistence.core-2.6.2.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:582) ~[org.eclipse.persistence.core-2.6.2.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.postConnectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:818) ~[org.eclipse.persistence.core-2.6.2.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:762) ~[org.eclipse.persistence.core-2.6.2.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:265) ~[org.eclipse.persistence.jpa-2.6.2.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:731) ~[org.eclipse.persistence.jpa-2.6.2.jar:na]
    ... 124 common frames omitted
```

Date time fields are problematic as they don't contain TS as a suffix:

```
@Column(name = "CREATE_TIME")
private DateTime createTime;
```

Is there any workaround or the way how to turn such behavior off?

Comment: I'm not sure where your exception is coming from, but it is not an EclipseLink restriction.  Are you not able to just change the field name to CREATE_TIME_TS using Column(name = "CREATE_TIME_TS") if it is the database restriction?

Comment: I have updated the question, added stacktrace where you can see it comes from org.eclipse.persistence.internal.* My problem is I can't change db schema as spring batch internal tables have to stay as they are.

Comment: Are you using org.joda.time.DateTime?  
Try with java.util.Date

Comment: Hi Dmitry, java.util.Date is the way to go. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used java.util.Date instead of org.joda.time.DateTime to solve the issue as suggested by Dmitry in comments below the question